# Magento 2.2.6 Cannot create a symlink for... after Update

Tags: upgrade, magento2.2.6, symlinks

I update my magento webstore to 2.2.6 using following guide:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html

Not everything seems to be fine. I have some css files that do not get generated (calendar.css for example). When I try to view the source of these files in the browser I get following error:

> annot create a symlink for "C:/xampp/htdocs/magitas/lib/web/mage/calendar.css" and place it to "C:/xampp/htdocs/magitas/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/nl_NL/mage/calendar.css" Warning!symlink(): Cannot create symlink, error code(1314)

I tried changing the theme from  my own theme to magento/luma but I got the same message.

I also tried the `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f` command but with the same result.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found a solution in the `app/etc/di.xml` file I have changed the following

```
<virtualType name="developerMaterialization" type="Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Factory">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="strategiesList" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="view_preprocessed" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink</item>
            <item name="default" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

to:

```
<virtualType name="developerMaterialization" type="Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Factory">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="strategiesList" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="view_preprocessed" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy</item>
            <item name="default" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

`<item name="view_preprocessed"...` has been modified in the above code.

Comment: Yeah, it works after applying the above solution

Comment: wow. worked. thanks a lot manh